# Indeed.com API job search India

Tags: api

I want to create a job feed using indeed.com API. I created a publisher account on indeed.com and received API token,secret key and publisher id. For testing purposes, I hit the URL
http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=9191150085731087&v=2&limit=100&l=Bangalore%2C+Karnataka&q=java (changed publisher id) . But it returns zero results, where as same query returns many results on indeed.co.in website. Am I missing out any region configurations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tried a little more digging and colleague gave the answer. The default country if unspecified is USA, which can be configured to India using co=India.

Comment: Mark it as answered. Thanks